# Google Sheets / Apps Script - Add Duplicated Data Together - If Col A & Col B are the same

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to combine rows of data where they match in Col A & Col B only.

In the example 1 - you can see 2 rows of Guitar D in Aisle 7 - Then the **expected result** of combining the duplicates together.

[image]

So combine the Qty`s together and list the latest date.

I am sorry I have no code to offer as an example as i cannot find something similar.

I do appreciate any help.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. If you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script, can you provide your current script? 2. In your sample image of Spreadsheet, the cells "A2:D" are used as the source range. Is this situation the same with your actual situation? 3. When the same values of "SKU" are existing and the values of "LOCATION" are different, what result do you want to retrieve?

Comment: 1. If you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script, can you provide your current script? I am sorry I dont have any script this time.i looked for soem but cannot find.

Comment: 2. In your sample image of Spreadsheet, the cells "A2:D" are used as the source range. Is this situation the same with your actual situation? yes exactly the same

Comment: 3. When the same values of "SKU" are existing and the values of "LOCATION" are different, what result do you want to retrieve? Nothing should happen. only duplicates should be added together

Comment: I'm not sure whether the rows in the source sheet are always sorted with "SKU", "LOCATION" and "DATE". So I proposed 2 patterns for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to achieve the image in your question.

  - Also, in your actual situation, the cells "A2:D" are used as the source range.
  - When the same values of "SKU" are existing and the values of "LOCATION" are different, the rows are not merged. Only when both values of "SKU" and "LOCATION" are the same, the rows are merged.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, as your sample image, it supposes that the rows in the source sheet are sorted with "SKU", "LOCATION" and "DATE".

#### Sample script:

In this sample, it supposes that the source values are put in the sheet name of `source` and the output values are put to the sheet name of `destination`. So please modify them for your actual situation.

```
function myFnunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const dstValues = srcValues.reduce((o, r) => {
    if (r[0] == o.temp[0] && r[1] == o.temp[1]) {
      o.temp[2] += r[2];
      o.temp[3] = r[3];
    } else {
      o.ar.push(o.temp.length == 0 ? r : o.temp);
      o.temp = r;
    }
    return o;
  }, {ar: [], temp: []});

  // 3. Put the values to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("destination");
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, dstValues.ar.length, dstValues.ar[0].length).setValues(dstValues.ar);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, as your sample image, it supposes that the rows in the source sheet are NOT sorted with "SKU", "LOCATION" and "DATE".

#### Sample script:

In this sample, it supposes that the source values are put in the sheet name of `source` and the output values are put to the sheet name of `destination`. So please modify them for your actual situation.

```
function myFnunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("source");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const dstObj = srcValues.reduce((o, r) => Object.assign(o, {[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`]: (o[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`] ? [o[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`][0], o[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`][1], o[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`][2] + r[2], (o[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`][3].getTime() < r[3].getTime() ? r[3] : o[`${r[0]}_${r[1]}`][3])] : r)}), {});
  const dstValues = Object.values(dstObj);

  // 3. Put the values to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("destination");
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)